# Как записывать данные в эксель в цикле без переноса строки в листе при записи?

Tags: python, excel, dict, xlsx

Как записывать данные в эксель в цикле без переноса строки в листе при записи?
Записываю вложенный словарь в эксель по колонкам, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, при записи значений словаря в цикле, каждое отдельное значение переносится на следующую строку на листе в эксель файле.

Код выглядит так:

```
a = {'a1': {'b1': {'c11': [1, 5], 'c22': [2, 6]}},
     'a2': {'b2': {'c21': [3, 8], 'c22': [4, 1]}},
     'a3': {'b3': {'c31': [5, 6], 'c32': [6, 5], 'c33': [7, 4]}}}

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('тест.xlsx')
sheet = wb.add_worksheet('ТЕСТ')
row = 0
col = 0
for i in a.keys():
    sheet.write(row, col, i)
    for j in a[i].keys():
        wel_key = a[i]
        sheet.write(row, col + 1, j)
        for k in wel_key[j].keys():
            brd_key = wel_key[j]
            sheet.write(row, col + 2, k)
            v_col = 3
            for val in list(brd_key.values())[0]:
                sheet.write(row, v_col, str(val))
                v_col += 1
                row += 1
wb.close()
```

Текущий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `row += 1` вроде как должен быть в цикле по строкам, а не по ячейкам...

Comment: @Akina, прописывал write_row в цикле со значениями, но там совсем страшная каша получается

Comment: `row += 1` на один отступ влево должно быть

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось тривиальным, спасибо Эдуарду Измалкову!

```
for i in a.keys():
    sheet.write(row, col, i)
    for j in a[i].keys():
        wel_key = a[i]
        sheet.write(row, col + 1, j)
        for k in wel_key[j].keys():
            brd_key = wel_key[j]
            sheet.write(row, col + 2, k)
            v_col = 3
            row += 1
            for val in list(brd_key.values())[0]:
                sheet.write_row(row, v_col, str(val))
                v_col += 1
            row += 1   ###<---
```

Нужно было перенести параметр ряда `row` в цикл записи ключа словаря, в котором хранились значения.